# PHP item change on click with html dropdown menu

Tags: php, html

I have code and want to change language on click, there is code:

```
// define('APP_LANG', 'en');
// setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_EN');

 define('APP_LANG', 'ka');
 setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_EN');

// define('APP_LANG', 'fr');
// setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');
```

I want to change app_lang and setLocale on click.

How can I do that with also html toggle button?

Answer (score 2):

You can't change const variables dynamically, read [this](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.syntax.php)

So, you can store your language setting in $_SESSION and change that with ajax. Every time user makes the request, you should check this setting and select the translation according to this.

Comment: So i can't change language by dropdown like menu bar?